# How to use font_kerning_style in blf module?

Tags: python

I am drawing text in 3D_viewport using `blf` module and the letters are tightly closed together. How can I put some spacing between letters?

Comment: Blf module hasn't anything to do with text object properties... You would have to implement that yourself.

Comment: No, I want to use it in  `Font Drawing (blf)`

Comment: A solution to what *exactly*? The answer to your question (as it stands) is: No, you can not use `font_kerning_style` in conjunction with blf. Suggest take your time, add more detail to your question and elaborate on your goal.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/blf.html  Not sure how useful, can enable with `blf.enable(font_id, blf.KERNING_DEFAULT)`

Comment: I personally can not find any reliable way to adjust the kerning and `KERNING_DEFAULT` has no effect as far as I can see. I guess you either would have to display single letters and adjust their padding one by one or edit the actual font.